# Why does std::shuffle request URBG&& instead of URBG&?

Tags: c++

While looking at some of the documentation for the C++ standard library I came across `std::shuffle`. `std::shuffle` calls for a Uniform Random Bit Generator as input, but why does it require one to be passed as URBG&& instead of URBG&? I found it on this page: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: `URBG` is a template type, therefore `URBG&&` is a forwarding reference and will collapse to `URBG&` if given an l-value. However if it is given a temporary or a moved object it might be able to do something more efficient.

Comment: Oh wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: Now know as __Universal References__:  https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: @RichardCritten [forwarding references](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf) is the newer term.